# Is there a maximum limit for the number of lines written in file?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I have created an application that writes a file line by line.
My question is: Is there a maximum limit for the number of lines written in file?
I would need to write files containing 2000000 lines or more.

Comment: There is not a maximum limit of lines but personally I wouldn't use bufferedreader for this, there is most likely a custom java library online that deals with large data file manipulation better. Also, why would you need two million lines or more? Sounds like a waste of data, and I cannot imagine anything which would require this amount of lines.

Comment: That file would be really difficult to transfer or read, so _why_ would you want to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really an OS question, not a Java question. But since the @OP hasn't included the operating system they are using, there's really no good answer to this

Comment: There isn't fixed limit on number of lines, but there is a limit on maximum file size, depends on your operating system.

Comment: Restructure your question or edit tags since there is no clear connection between those two.

Comment: If all you're doing is writing (appending) lines to a file, why did you include tags `netbeans` and `bufferedreader`. `BufferedWriter` might be appropriate, but *reader*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit on number of lines that you can have in a file. Number of lines in a relation with max file size and that is limited by your operating system.

Comment: @JamesMcDowell How does heap size affect maximum file size, i.e. max number of lines in a file? As long as you don't try to load the entire file into memory, the heap size has no affect on this.